# Can a half-elf take human traits?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, races, traits

Can a half-elf raised by Varisian nomads take the trait [Varisian Tattoo](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/race-traits/varisian-tattoo-varisia/)?

Answer (score 22):

## A half-elf can take human race traits

The *Pathfinder Core Rulebook* FAQ includes [this exchange](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9qf9):

> **Half-Elf or Half-Orc: Can a character of either of these races select human racial archetypes (such as from *Advanced Race Guide*)?**
>
> Yes. Half-elves and half-orcs may select racial favored class options, archetypes, **traits**, and so on, as if they were a full member of both races (a half-elf can select elf and human rules elements, a half-orc can select human and orc rules elements).
>
> - *Edit 9/26/13:* This is a reversal of an earlier ruling. This resolves a discrepancy between this FAQ and two *Advanced Player's Guide* FAQs.

(Emphasis and formatting mine.)

Comment: +1 for searching the FAQ for this. Without pointing out that the ruling was reversed, the RAW description of Elf Blood would remain ambiguous.

Comment: @MikeQ Yeah, heated debate often ensued prior to the FAQ ruling, especially since no one was entirely sure if *being able to pick racially exclusive stuff* was an *effect.* It was particularly contentious with regards to half-orcs as many feats have prerequisites that specify *orc or half-orc* and why say *that* if half-orcs *already* count as orcs, right? (My half-orc inquisitor was pleased by—and benefited directly from—this FAQ ruling, by the way.)

Answer (score 9):

Half-elves count both as **human** and **elf** for any traits, feats, magic items or effects that work only on a certain race.

From the *core rulebook*:

> Elf Blood: Half-elves count as both elves and humans for any effect related to race.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but a frequent one and the other answers have missed a decisive rule from the [Advanced Race Guide](https://www.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Humanoid%20(0%20RP)&Category=Type%20Quality):

> Every humanoid creature also has a subtype to match its race, such as human, giant, goblinoid, reptilian, or tengu. If you are making a new humanoid race, you should either find an existing subtype to match or make a new one by using the name of the race as the subtype. If you are making a halfbreed race, it should have the racial type of both parent races. For example, a half-elf has both the human and the elf subtypes. Subtypes are often important to qualify for other racial abilities and feats. **If a humanoid has a racial subtype, it is considered a member of that race in the case of race prerequisites.**

This passage from the race creation rules should make the FAQ unnecessary, as the rules already say as much.

As for your example, since Half-Elves are Humanoids with the "Elf" subtype, they qualify for character options, that have "Elf" as a prerequisite.

This also renders the "Elf Blood" racial trait of Half-Elves moot, since they have the "Human" and "Elf" subtypes and therefore already count as humans and elves for racial prerequisites; the trait now only matters when a Half-Elf changes creature type to something other than Humanoid (e.g. Outsider as a 20th-level Monk).